# To convert if condition to linq in cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

Code

```
if(Model.CurrentStatus == 1 || Model.CurrentStatus == 2)
{
    //can display those records..
}
else if((Model.CurrentStatus == 3 || Model.CurrentStatus == 4) && Model.Date != null)
{
    if(Model.Date <= 30 days)
    {
        //can display those records..
    }
}
```

I have tried the following code and unable to complete it fully as expected

```
 @Html.Partial("Filter", new IndexModel() 
            { 
                Id = Model.Id, 
                Collection = Model.Collection.Where((a => a.CurrentStatus == 1 || a.CurrentStatus == 2)
                                                && ) 
            })
```

How to convert the above if condition to linq in cshtml. Thanks

Comment: why did you change the operator from OR to AND in the linq query? It seems to me that `CurrentStatus` cannot be `1` AND `2` at the same time...

Comment: An easy and readable way is add a CanDisplay method to your Model class with your conditions and use a => a.CanDisplay()

Comment: the else-if relationship is an OR relationship. So simply combine the two lines. the inner nested if inside the else if is an AND relationship. This would go into the second set of parentheses

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do this in Linq though? Does you code work? Is it readable? It will potentially be less readable in Linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the else-if relationship is an OR relationship. So simply combine the two lines. the inner nested if inside the else if is an AND relationship. This would go into the second set of parentheses

```
Collection = Model.Collection.Where
       (
          (a => a.CurrentStatus == 1 || a.CurrentStatus == 2) ||
          ((a.CurrentStatus == 3 || a.CurrentStatus == 4) && a.Date != null  && a.Date <= 30) 
       )
```

EDIT:

Here is another suggestion: extract the readable code into an own method that evaluates the condition and returns the boolean result. This way you can make a predicate that can be accepted by the `Where` method:

```
private bool IsForDisplay( ModelDataType Model )
{
    if(Model.CurrentStatus == 1 || Model.CurrentStatus == 2)
    {
        //can display those records..
        return true;
    }
    else if((Model.CurrentStatus == 3 || Model.CurrentStatus == 4) && Model.Date != null)
    {
        if(Model.Date <= 30 days)
        {
            //can display those records..
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

now you can use it simply in the linq expression:

```
 @Html.Partial("Filter", new IndexModel() 
                  { 
                       Id = Model.Id, 
                       Collection = Model.Collection.Where(a => IsForDisplay(a))
                   });
```

Comment: Well that Linq is awful, not sure it improves on OPs original structure.

Comment: @DavidG "Well that Linq is awful," I agree! horrible to read. OP hasn't told us yet what it is good for

Comment: @User you're welcome. I made an edit to retain the readability of your original code and still allow you to use linq

Comment: @DavidG I made an edit and made a mix to retain the readability.